# Cypress UAT testing on IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cypress

So it looks like there is no official support for ie with cypress js. I'm wondering if anybody knows about alternatives, hacks that can make this work at the moment?

Comment: If you came up with a different solution please, let us know, otherwise accept my answer. Both could be useful for other users looking for the same answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Cypress with IE at all at the moment so you have two choices for testing IE:

- rewrite your tests for Selenium and use Selenium IE webdriver
- rewrite your tests for TestCafè and use it in every browser you want
- wait for Cypress IE support